# Elasticsearch setup and usage with Kibana using Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

How can we pull and use docker image of elasticsearch ? 
 I pulled latest image and run `docker run -d elasticsearch -p 9200:9200` , but when I access http://0.0.0.0:9200/ connection got refused. Again, when I tried with `curl` command the result was same.
 I checked whether it is running or not by `docker ps` command and it's status is running. How can I use graphical user interface(GUI) like **Kibana** dashboard by this `elasticsearch` image ?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to elastic search [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) you will find the problem, as it default ships with X-Pack and the access denied problem is due to that.
I guess this will solve the problem of yours.

And no you can't use the same image to run Kibana on that, you needed Kibana image for that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official [dockerhub page for elastic-seacrh](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/).

**Running the container:**

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 9300:9300 elasticsearch
```

The API can then be accessed on `http://localhost:9200`

---

The [kibana image](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/_pulling_the_image.html) is a separate image and it should be started separately. Check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html to see how to start the kibana container and connect it to elastic-search.